# How to Convert array inside single object to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was got single row of record into mysql via node and express js but returned result are this array inside object

output of result

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "name": "Aravinth",
        "email": "anthu1510@gmail.com",
        "password": "sha1$4bd1aa7a$1$21b6700d0949cfd187f41f8d05be550bc5b0e5a9",
        "age": 27,
        "city": "Coimbatore",
        "status": "active",
        "created_at": "2020-02-20T07:25:59.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-20T07:25:59.000Z"
    }
]
```

but i only want object code

```
{
            "user_id": 1,
            "name": "Aravinth",
            "email": "anthu1510@gmail.com",
            "password": "sha1$4bd1aa7a$1$21b6700d0949cfd187f41f8d05be550bc5b0e5a9",
            "age": 27,
            "city": "Coimbatore",
            "status": "active",
            "created_at": "2020-02-20T07:25:59.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-20T07:25:59.000Z"
        }
```

how to convert array inside single object to object

Comment: yourArray[0] will have only the object

Comment: thats okey but any default function are the i want that also

Answer (score 2):

convert to array into object

```
let result = queryResult;

for (let index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
    let Obj = result[index];
    console.log("Obj", Obj);

}
```